# Laravel 5.4 User model not updating

Tags: model, controller, laravel-5.4

I know this question has been asked a dozen times and I've gone through a few but none seem to resolve my issue.

I have the following \App\User model:

```
namespace App;

use Hash;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use \App\Traits\HasUuid;
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'zoho_id', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
```

and I'm trying to update it a form. The following headers are sent:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

sean
------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

sean@someplace.net
------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roles[]"

2
------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="zoho"

56511561681616
------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password_confirmation"

------WebKitFormBoundaryb66NOeoCh473wkB7--
```

This goes to the following UserController to the update function:

```
public function update(Request $Request, $id) {
        $User = User::findOrFail($id); //Get role specified by id

        //Validate name, email and password fields  
        $validator = Validator::make($Request->all(), [
            'name'      =>  'required|max:120',
            'email'     =>  'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'roles.*'   =>  'nullable|exists:roles,id',
            'password'  =>  'nullable|bail|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);

        $User->name = $Request->get('name');
        $User->zoho_id = $Request->get('zoho');
        if(!empty($Request->get('password'))){
            $User->password = $Request->get('password');
        }

        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $User->save();

            $User->roles()->sync($Request->get('roles'));  //If one or more role is selected associate user to roles

            return response()->json('"' . $Request->get('name') . '" updated successfully!', 200);      

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            DB::rollback();

            return response()->json('An error occured updating the user.', 500);
        }
    }
```

The URL it Posts to is: http://ml.someplace.net/system/users/1/edit

It is in my routes file as the following: `Route::post('/system/users/{user}/edit', 'UserController@update');`

I've done dumps and can see the Model is updated before and after the save, but going into the database, nothing is updated, including the "updated_at" column.

Any suggestions on this one is appreciated, losing my mind with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `DB::commit()` following your `DB::beginTransaction()`; if you don't include that, nothing is "saved", as the transaction is lost (which is essentially the same as `DB::rollBack()`.)

Adjust your code as follows:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try{
  $User->save();
  $User->roles()->sync($Request->get('roles'));  //If one or more role is selected associate user to roles
} catch(PDOException $e){
  DB::rollback();
  return response()->json('An error occured updating the user.', 500);
}

DB::commit();

return response()->json('"' . $Request->get('name') . '" updated successfully!', 200);
```

(`beginTransaction()` and `commit()` can be inside or outside the `try/catch`, I lean towards outside for readability)

With that in place, when the code inside the `try` passes without issue, the changes are committed to the DB and your `return` is executed.

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me nuts, don't know how I didn't see it.

Comment: No worries; it's an easy thing to overlook. Glad you got it working though, cheers.